# How do I build an Electron wrapper for my existing web app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I currently have a Web App (Bootstrap/JavaScript/JQuery at the frontend and Laravel at the backend). I'd like to build a Electron desktop app that will basically just act like a browser. But the one Electron feature I really need is to be able to write(directly) to usb POS( Point of Sale) receipt printer.
How can I do that?

Comment: Which sort of USB printer? What are the specifications for it, and how are you supposed to communicate with it?

Comment: So, I'm going to implement an abstraction layer to allow for writing to a generic USB connected printer. Basically, at a lower level, on a UNIX machine, the end result will be similar to
```printf "One line of text\nAnother line of text.........."  >> /dev/usb/lp1```

Comment: @Kola did you find any solution? I'm looking for the same